# What's the lowest price for a ship that one can talk Stan down to in The Secret of Monkey Island?

Tags: the-secret-of-monkey-island

I know that you can't buy your ship from Stan without doing some bargaining.

I've been able to bargain enough to make it so that I can afford the ship, but I'm curious what the lowest possible price you can talk him down to is.

Comment: Just remember that in Monkey Island games, [you can't lose](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311591/4837), so you can confidently offer him the kitchen sink!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SPOILER:

> You can only talk him down to 5000. He won't go lower. Sorry, but the game's gonna make sure you're broke before you get to Monkey Island itself. :)

Answer (score 14):

Actually, I just made Stan accept 4000. You first offer him 3000 3-4 times and then 4000, once or twice, and he'll accept it. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4):

We were playing through the Special Edition - and we somehow were able to get it for 3000! [Clip here](https://clips.twitch.tv/PhilanthropicProudDuckPogChamp), but you can watch the [full broadcast here](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/743223031)

Answer (score 2):

I actually made him sell it to me for 3000

I asked him about all the extras, and told him that I don't need any of them.
Then asked him what he thinks the ship is worth, and he said 4700.
I offered 3000 and - **BAM** - he accepted :)

Comment: What's the saying? _Pics or it didn't happen!_